# Initializing a variable in the same line as a for loop for specific counter in python?

Tags: python-3.x

We now have a walrus operator in python which is great because I can assign a variable inside a for a loop.

So now I can do:

```
for i in (list := [1,2,2,2,4]):
    pass

print(list)
```

This means I can use the new variable outside the for loop.

However, can I assign a variable at the beginning of a for loop or in the same line?

So that I could do something like this:

```
counter = 0 for i in (list := [1,2,2,2,4]):
    if i == 2:
        counter += 1
```

or even better in an if statement?

```
for i in (list := [1,2,2,2,4]):
    if i == 2, counter := 0:
        counter += 1
```

I understand this example is not the best but it does illustrate my point and the question the idea might reduce the number of times I have to initialize a var at 0 that I end up not using.

I also know python has enumerate() but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Note that you're not initalizing `counter` to `None`. You're initializing it to zero, and presumably the point at which you do so needs to be _outside_ the loop, otherwise it doesn't make sense. The only time you should be using the walrus operator is when doing otherwise would cause you to repeat yourself (e.g. with `re.match()`) - it's generally going to be more clear, easier to understand, and maintainable to declare `lst = [1, 2, 2, 2, 4]; for i in lst` than it will be to do so with the walrus operator.

Comment: Sorry, yes 0 not None but I often declare it to None. For a for loops inside of another for loop I find it useful to use the walrus operator but I agree that it is more clear to declare it outside the for loop normally. Well, that is what I'm asking if there is a better syntax where i might introduce it into the same line. Which if its the sole purpose of the for loop it does not matter for clarity.

Comment: For this case, you could do `sum(1 for i in list if i == 2)`, Maybe edit your question to include a better example?

Comment: Minor thing but `list` is a built-in, you shouldn't name things `list`

Comment: I believe you're trying to solve problems with the walrus operator that I don't think need solving, since they're simple enough as is. Defining `counter`, for example, is perfectly acceptable. You wouldn't want to have it in the if statement or anything like that, and one extra line of `counter = 0` is totally fine. Though this particular problem is easily solved by @OneCricketeer 's solution

Comment: @OneCricketeer Since Python coerces booleans in sums to `int`, one can do `sum(i == 2 for i in list)`.